# Failed to install cuda on centos 7

Tags: centos-7, cuda

Following the instructions to install the cuda found here:
https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html

e.g.

```
$ sudo yum groupinstall "Development tools"
$ sudo yum install kernel-devel-$(uname -r) kernel-headers-$(uname -r)
$ wget https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/rhel7/x86_64/cuda-repo-rhel7-10.0.130-1.x86_64.rpm
$ sudo rpm -i cuda-repo-rhel7-10.0.130-1.x86_64.rpm
$ sudo yum clean expire-cache
$ sudo yum install cuda
```

the "yum install cuda" is giving these errors:

```
Error: Package: 3:nvidia-driver-libs-410.72-1.el7.x86_64 (cuda)
           Requires: libglvnd-gles(x86-64) >= 0.2
Error: Package: 3:nvidia-driver-libs-410.72-1.el7.x86_64 (cuda)
           Requires: libglvnd-egl(x86-64) >= 0.2
Error: Package: 3:nvidia-driver-libs-410.72-1.el7.x86_64 (cuda)
           Requires: libglvnd-opengl(x86-64) >= 0.2
Error: Package: 3:nvidia-driver-libs-410.72-1.el7.x86_64 (cuda)
           Requires: libglvnd-glx(x86-64) >= 0.2
Error: Package: 3:nvidia-driver-libs-410.72-1.el7.x86_64 (cuda)
           Requires: libglvnd(x86-64) >= 0.2
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I'm running a VM in Google Cloud with 2 K80's attached to it. I've used this formula before without problems. Seems like something has changed.

Update:
I can confirm that the cuda 10 rpm works on RHEL 7.5 and that the cuda 7.0 rpm on Centos 7 doesn't work on Centos 7 either.
https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/rhel7/x86_64/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a Centos 7 system that already had the cuda libraries and nvidia drivers already installed, it appears the libglvnd-*packages came from epel.

```
$ yum info libglvnd-gles
...
Installed Packages
Name        : libglvnd-gles
Arch        : x86_64
Epoch       : 1
Version     : 1.0.1
Release     : 0.1.git5baa1e5.el7
Size        : 118 k
Repo        : installed
From repo   : epel
Summary     : GLES support for libglvnd
URL         : https://github.com/NVIDIA/libglvnd
License     : MIT
Description : libGLESv[12] are the common dispatch interface for the GLES API.
```

However it appears that it has been removed from epel. In rhel 7 it is found in a different repo.

```
$ yum info libglvnd-gles
...
Name        : libglvnd-gles
Arch        : x86_64
Epoch       : 1
Version     : 1.0.1
Release     : 0.8.git5baa1e5.el7
Size        : 34 k
Repo        : rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-rpms/7Server/x86_64
Summary     : GLES support for libglvnd
URL         : https://github.com/NVIDIA/libglvnd
License     : MIT
Description : libGLESv[12] are the common dispatch interface for the GLES API.
```

I found that using the [runfile](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads?target_os=Linux&target_arch=x86_64&target_distro=CentOS&target_version=7&target_type=runfilelocal), instead of the rpm, does work in Centos 7.5 though.

Update:
Something happened and the rpm install now works.

```
$ yum info libglvnd-gles
...
Installed Packages
Name        : libglvnd-gles
Arch        : x86_64
Epoch       : 1
Version     : 1.0.1
Release     : 0.6.git5baa1e5.el7
Size        : 118 k
Repo        : installed
From repo   : cuda
Summary     : GLES support for libglvnd
URL         : https://github.com/NVIDIA/libglvnd
License     : MIT
Description : libGLESv[12] are the common dispatch interface for the GLES API.
```

Answer (score 2):

This driver needs RHEL 7.6 files.
For what I know, Centos 7.6 is still not released, so to update to 410; you need to wait for Centos 7.6, update, and install driver :-)

Hope this helps.

Ox

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT 2018-11-26**: I just wanted to update this answer to say that CentOS has now advanced to 7.6, and `yum update` once again works fine - the dependencies are correctly pulled in and everything works. This means you can ignore everything I said below :)

---

As **oxedions**' answer states, it seems like Nvidia's repo has updated to RHEL 7.6 files but CentOS is still on 7.5, so you'll have to wait for them to update.

To add a bit more information, based on the normal amount of time between a RHEL release and a CentOS release it should be out within a month to a month and a half. RHEL 7.5, for example, was released on April 10th, with CentOS 7.5 coming out May 10th.

In the meantime you can try installing the older version of the driver (i think 390 still works), but then every time you do a `yum update` you'll get an error like this:

```
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: 3:nvidia-driver-libs-410.72-1.el7.x86_64 (cuda)
           Requires: libglvnd-gles(x86-64) >= 0.2
Error: Package: 3:nvidia-driver-libs-410.72-1.el7.x86_64 (cuda)
           Requires: libglvnd-egl(x86-64) >= 0.2
Error: Package: 3:nvidia-driver-libs-410.72-1.el7.x86_64 (cuda)
           Requires: libglvnd-opengl(x86-64) >= 0.2
Error: Package: 3:nvidia-driver-libs-410.72-1.el7.x86_64 (cuda)
           Requires: libglvnd-glx(x86-64) >= 0.2
Error: Package: 3:nvidia-driver-libs-410.72-1.el7.x86_64 (cuda)
           Requires: libglvnd(x86-64) >= 0.2
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

The `--skip-broken` flag will let you continue on and do the update anyway, but (at least in my case) it leaves nearly 100 packages back due to dependencies:

```
Transaction Summary
=========================================================================================
Install                         2 Packages (+7 Dependent packages)
Upgrade                        49 Packages
Remove                          2 Packages
Skipped (dependency problems)  95 Packages
```

I suppose there's also ways to force upgrade to RHEL 7.6 but that seems like an even worse idea.